# Netsuite Debit Card Processing

Tags: netsuite, payment-processing, erp

I have  some basic knowledge of Netsuite. Recently I added up in one of the ERP project where the customer can use either Debit/Credit card for making payments. Using credit cards we can process the SO and create the invoice that I aware of. But How could we process the same with a Debit card ?

e.g : Say my customer wants to pay the deposit with a debit card and want to schedule the remaining due on a specific interval. Is it possible with current Netsuite  functionality ? I was just wondering, if somebody could insight a better direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to accept the deposit on a project using one form of payment and then use another form of payment for ongoing billings.

If I have that right, you can create a customer deposit with the debit card and then use either a memorized cash sale for the remainder of the payments using any other form of payment. Debit and credit cards are treated basically the same in NetSuite, so you should be able to use either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TonyHill. Actually I had a glitch that scheduling payments on a Debit card may not be supported as there is always a chance of insufficient amount and card rejection.